# SwiftUI: A list with a DatePicker and Text mangles the display

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-text, swiftui-datepicker

On iOS 15, if you display a `List` of `VStack`s with a `Text` and `DatePicker` as below

```swift
@main
struct WeirdListDatePickerProblem: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
 
struct ContentView: View {
    let listRows: [Int] = (0...100).map { $0 }
    var body: some View {
        List(listRows, id: \.self) { v in
            RowView()
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("If you remove this then the problem disappears")
            DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

then the screen is mangled as below.

[image]

It becomes worse the more you scroll. This has been seen on the simulator and on a real device using iOS 15.5 with Xcode 13.4.1.

If you remove the `Text` then the problem disappears.

How, on iOS 15, can you display list items with a `Text` and `DatePicker` without the above happening?

Comment: Works fine on iOS 16, just be aware.

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 here

Comment: Are you scrolling the list?

Comment: are you joking? :) - sure

Comment: Strange. I can reproduce this on my iPhone easily. iOS 15.5.

Comment: I get the same issue on real device iPhone ios 15.6, when scrolling fast. No problems on macCatalyst macos Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me:

the issue goes away for me, when I add a `.frame(width: 333, height: 88)` to the `RowView()`, or its `VStack{...}`. It seems the `List` view needs a `height` for its rows to work properly. I also noticed it is much faster to scroll with the added frame.

Comment: did my answer not work for you?